# How to create an iOS app build using command line tool without Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native-ios, command-line-tool

I have a question regarding the iOS build. I just want to know that is it possible or not so the question is--

is it possible to create a build using command line tool for iOS app without Xcode. Xcode is not installed and project is created in React Native.

any suggestion or idea for this will be helpful.

Comment: You need Xcode because that is how you get the tool chain

Comment: @Paulw11 so to create a build Xcode is compulsory.

Comment: Yes you need xcode to make a build. Even on the command line, it uses xcode's tool chain to do the build. You can create Swift linux applications without xcode, but not iOS applications

Comment: You can build without the Xcode _GUI_. See `man xcodebuild` to for more info about the command line Xcode build system.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is you cannot.

The only half workaround is to use a CI like CircleCI so you can push your builds to the CI however the CI itself will need to have xcode on it.